# Machine learning - Features contain list of values

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-cleaning, data-processing

I have a dataset that contains many features. I have one features that contain a list of values in one data point. It's can be like this :

```
A B C
1 2 [3,4,5]
```

So what can we handle features C for recommendation system?. I have known about one hot encoding but my features C doesn't have finite values. C contain ID number of others therefore it can become larger and larger overtime. Is there any solution to deal with this type of features?

Answer (score 0):

From what you described and since you mentioned about recommendation system,  I would consider your data set as an example of following: 
per row is a user and feature A, B are user personal information for instance and feature C is the items he bought. And of course, feature C doesn't contain the same numbers of items in each row and it can expand.

I would build two different recommendation models and combine them together afterward. One for feature A, B and another is for feature C. 
Since feature C evolves with time, you can build the model on regular time base (take the snapshot of the feature C) or as long as some 'event" triggers the building process. For feature C, in my example, is user-item matrices.